# How do I retrieve information online using python?

Tags: python

So this is basically the problem: I have this application that receives information and saves it using a json file, but I want to save it in a way that, if someone elses have the same app in their computer, they will receive the things I update in my own.

I think I can use Http and make some import to python, but I know nothing about http, so if theres a solution in python for this it would be better. If there's nothing in python, what do you think is the more simple way of doing it ?

Anyway, thanks ahead for those responding.

edit: That's the code, now the only problem is to upload it online.

```
import json
import requests
import atexit

r = requests.get('https://github.com/Gevez/gameficacao/blob/master/data-teste.json')

with open('data-teste.json','wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

def exit_handler():
    url = 'https://github.com/Gevez/gameficacao/blob/master/'
    contents = open('data-teste.json', 'rb').read()
    r = requests.post(url, data=contents, headers=headers)

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Comment: For importing HTML to Python, check out beautifulsoup.  https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python .  However, you seem to have another issue, in that you want other folks to read these things from your machine.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: Not really, I want folks to have this updated on their computer without the need of them reading from my machine, and as I could see, requests (and the beautifulsoup library) does it well. The thing is, can I only interact directly to the internet page ? I am trying to figure out if I can use request to only upload or take a json file, in this case, I wouldn't save information in the internet page, I would save in the json file in my app and then I would upload this file, and eventually I would pull it back to load info. Is this possible ?

Comment: If you want folks to have things updated on their computer, then you either have to put the information on a local network/ or the Internet (using a hosting service).  I don't know if Dropbox would work, as a proof of concept.  If the data direction is only one way, that might work.   Having people read data from a file that you provide is relatively easy; the issue is where the data is located.   You could also use other protocols, depending on what sort of data you are providing.

Comment: yess, that's what i'm trying to do. But to make things simple, I just want to upload my file into one of those hosting services and "load" it when I open my app, those are the 2 actions that I want to use request for

Comment: ok so I managed to take the file from the internet successfully, Now I need to know how I can save it in the page (I'm using github), I'm gonna update my post with the code I'm trying to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/). Making http requests with this library is pretty easy, if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: So, requests is apparently what I needed, but I want to use in a especific way. The thing is, can I only interact directly to the internet page ? I am trying to figure out if I can use request to only upload or take a json file, in this case, I wouldn't save information in the internet page, I would save in the json file in my app and then I would upload this file, and eventually I would pull it back to load info. Is this possible ?